# Use comparison of two images as if condition

Tags: bash, compare, imagemagick

In my bash script, I want to do something like the following:

```
if  [ compare $image1 $image2 ] = 1; then // if images are graphically equal
rm $image2
fi
```

Any idea?

Comment: You can compare any physical properties like filename, filetype, size, dimensions etc of 2 files by capturing those in a variable and comparing them. I don't think bash can do any graphical comparison or direct image comparison.

Comment: Do these files have identical `md5sum`?

Comment: @LohitGupta: that is what the command compare does on linux.

Comment: For the OP, why not?  Try it!

Comment: @Arkadiusz Drabczyk  No, they don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in ImageMagick as follows. The rmse metric of 0 means identical. The compare writes to stderr so you need to add 2>&1. The compare result is 0 (0), where the first is in the range 0 to quantum range and the second in parens is in the range 0 to 1. So I use cut to get just the first 0. The compare output is set to null: so that the compare does not create any output image. Note that there are two spaces after the -d\

```
convert lena.png lena2.png

[ $(compare -metric rmse lena.png lena2.png null: 2>&1 | cut -d\  -f1) -eq 0 ] && rm lena2.png
```